# Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'hour'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from cProfile import label
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
day = [1/17,1/18,1/19,1/20,1/21,1/22,]
kid1 = [1,2,3,4,5,24]
plt.plot(day, kid1, 'r--*', lw=2, ms=10, label="Ryan")
kid2 = [0,1,2,3,24,2]
plt.plot(day, kid2, 'c-..', lw=2, ms=10,label="Kyile")
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(50, 250)
plt.xticks("hour")
plt.title("hung's kid's happy time", fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel("hour",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("day",fontsize=12)
plt.grid(color="k", ls='-', lw=1, alpho=0.5)
plt.show()from cProfile import label
```

This is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jessiecheng/Desktop/python/plot.py", line 10, in <module>
    plt.xticks("hour")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1788, in xticks
    locs = ax.set_xticks(ticks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return get_method(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1855, in set_ticks
    result = self._set_tick_locations(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1804, in _set_tick_locations
    ticks = self.convert_units(ticks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1508, in convert_units
    raise munits.ConversionError('Failed to convert value(s) to axis '
matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'hour'
```

I have checked everything, what have been wrong? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`plt.xticks` expects a list of numbers indicating where the tick marks on the x-axis should go. You can see examples [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). The problem here is that you passed a string, `"hours"`, to this function and it doesn't know how to convert that to locations on the x-axis.

Comment: Also, OP should look at examples (starting with [this one](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_demo_convert.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-date-demo-convert-py)?) for using a date axis.